# Global line numbering is intermittent -- conflict with global whitespace

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I have `(global-linum-mode 1)` and `(global-whitespace-mode t)` defined in my init.el with Aquamacs 2.4.  Line numbering is intermittent, and skips displaying a line number following an empty line.  Disabling whitespaces fixes the problem.  Is there any way to display a line number for every line and also have whitespace enabled?

Perhaps there is an alternative to linum.el that does something very similar?

In the following example, the dollar sign is an empty line with no text.

```
1  First line.
2  Second line.
3  $
   Fourth line.
5  $
   Sixth Line.
7  Seventh line.
8  $
   Ninth line.
```

Comment: *(not an answer to your question hence the comment)*... Instead of showing every whitespace I do use *ethan-wspace* and it is configured to show every single trailing whitespace in red (because it typically is a mistake) and every tab in the color your want (I'm using red because I'm allergic to tabs but YMMV).  I'm using *ethan-wspace* since quite a while and, IMHO, it does the "Right Thing" [TM] : )

Comment: I just tried ethan-wspace and got error messages when quitting (using `(global-ethan-wspace-mode 1)`) and there was no discernible effect when using the script.  I submitted an issue to the author along with the error message.

Comment: @lawlist Aquamacs is based on a rather out-dated Emacs 23.x version.  Build Aquamacs from source, or use raw GNU Emacs 24.3 to get a decent version of Emacs.  These issues might be fixed in a new version.

Comment: I've narrowed down the conflict to `(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark))`.  Specifically, `whitespace.el` and `linum.el` are at issue.  I will check the various varieties of newer Emacs builds to see if those particular files have been changed (in any way) since the last stable release of Aquamacs 2.4.  My next step will be to see if I can modify `linum.el` to remove the space before the line number and perhaps replace it with an invisible character other than a space.

Comment: Yep, that was it ... the default line numbering of `linum.el` inserts spaces before every line number, and those spaces are what causes the conflict with `space-mark` of `whitespace.el`.  I will post a few workarounds in an answer . . . .

Comment: I can see similar problems with the newer `nlinum-mode`.  You should report this via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution # 1 -- from http://www.emacswiki.org/LineNumbers (citing Michael Hoffman) - posted there for a different reason, but resolves my problem also:

```
(eval-after-load 'linum
  '(progn
     (defface linum-leading-zero
       `((t :inherit 'linum
            :foreground ,(face-attribute 'linum :background nil t)))
       "Face for displaying leading zeroes for line numbers in display margin."
       :group 'linum)

     (defun linum-format-func (line)
       (let ((w (length
                 (number-to-string (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
         (concat
          (propertize (make-string (- w (length (number-to-string line))) ?0)
                      'face 'linum-leading-zero)
          (propertize (number-to-string line) 'face 'linum))))

     (setq linum-format 'linum-format-func)))
```

---

Solution # 2:

```
(setq linum-format "%d")
```

---

F.Y.I. # A:

For anyone who is wondering how to resolve a related issue where various whitespace colorations (and/or highlight the current line) invade the left-hand margin that is reserved for line numbering, setting the background coloration of that area fixes the issue.  The foreground and/or background of the line numbers can be user-defined.  Solution number one above can be modified also by adding a color definitation after the word `foreground` at line 5 -- e.g., `:foreground "red", ...`  The following snippet is a separate line that would either precede or follow the entire workaround mentioned in solution number one, and modified with whatever colors the user desires:

```
(custom-set-faces '(linum ((t (:foreground "red" :background "white" :height 120 :family "Courier")))) )
```

F.Y.I. # B:  I modified line 13 of solution number one to eliminate the `0` and replace it with a plain old space because I'm not accustomed to seeing the leading zeroes and was just looking for a solution to the initial issue described in this thread.  Solution number 2 appears to be flush-left and solution number 1 is flush-right.  Just a matter of personal preference.  There are undoubtedly several other possibilities for changing the `linum-format` to something other than the dynamic default defined within `linum.el`.